# how to convert findElementByAndroidUIAutomator in Page Factory Format for Appium

Tags: java, android, selenium-webdriver, appium, appium-android

I am currently designing Appium Android framework based on page object and page Factory.

I have a below line of code which uses "findElementByAndroidUIAutomator".

```
driver.findElementByAndroidUIAutomator("new UiScrollable(new UiSelector()).scrollIntoView(text(\"Brazil\"));");
```

I wanted to convert it to page Factory format like below example.

```
@AndroidFindBy(id="android:id/text1")
    public WebElement clickOnDropDown;
```

As I checked I didn't not find any definite answers regarding this.
Just wanted to check as  findElementByAndroidUIAutomator is android function not appium. So how can we convert this line to page factory format ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```java
@AndroidFindBy(uiAutomator = "new UiScrollable(new UiSelector()).scrollIntoView(text(\"Brazil\"));")
public WebElement brazilLabel;
```

The only downside is that you can't pass argument ("e.g Brazil") to annotation

Comment: So is it a better option for such case is creating new method in Utility case like below and call it in a test ?

Comment: public void scrollToText(String text) {
  driver.findElementByAndroidUIAutomator("new UiScrollable(new UiSelector()).scrollIntoView(text(\""+text+"\"));");
 }

Comment: if your case is flexible argument in locator, then you just have to use a function